# Remove newline-character

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

I have a file which looks like this:

```
1

2

3

4
5
6
7
```

I want to read it in and remove the newline characters. My attempt is this:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("t.txt");
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ");
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

But the output is still the same as above. I want the output to be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable, the string being returned by replace should be formatted like you expect.

Comment: Maybe OP could need a code example ;-)

Comment: i.e. `text = text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ");`